# Facebook SDK - how to get started

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

Could you please point me out to some tutorials for facebook SDK.

I would like to write a desktop app that is just taking a photo and it's posting it on a page wall.

Is there any way for doing this in C# code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an unofficial sdk here for C#: http://csharpsdk.org/

It also contains tutorials.